# Prolog Subtract List Unification

Tags: prolog

I am trying to subtract one list from another in prolog. In my program the input list have blank spaces in them (e.g. [1,2,_,4])

I am getting the following output:

```
?- subtract([1,2,3,4],[3,4,_],L).

L = [2].
```

when I want my output to be

```
L = [1,2].
```

So my question is how can I prevent the blank spaces from unifying with other elements? Have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: That's not a "blank space", that's an anonymous variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the "blank spaces" to be ignored, you can simply make a version of each list with those removed and compute their difference:

```
listWOblanks( [], [] ).
listWOblanks( [H|T], Tx ) :- var(H), !,  listWOblanks( T, Tx ).
listWOblanks( [H|T], [H|Tx] ) :- listWOblanks( T, Tx ).
```

If, when the first list has a blank and the second does not, you need the result to still have a blank, you could modify the above to add a 3rd argument that tells you if any blanks were removed so you can correct the difference accordingly.  I believe SWI-Prolog has a predicate, ground, which will tell you if a term has no variables in it, which would do the job w/o needing to modify listWOblanks.

Comment: Please don't feed the OP's confusion by calling anonymous variables blanks. They're not; `' '` is a blank.

Comment: Actually, `' '` (0x20) is the _space_ character (SP), not a blank :D

Answer (score 0):

larsmans is correct, the `_` is an *anonymous variable*, and the definition of `lists:subtract/3` (which I'm assuming you're using in SWI-Prolog) will always unify them to ground list members because of it's definition using `memberchk/2`.

If you want `subtract` behaviour where variables are to be treated like ground terms, then you can redefine it like this:

```
subtract2([], _, []) :- !.
subtract2([A|C], B, D) :-
    var_memberchk(A, B), !,
    subtract2(C, B, D).
subtract2([A|B], C, [A|D]) :-
    subtract2(B, C, D).
```

Note that `subtract2/3` here is nearly the same as the definition of `lists:subtract/3` (try `listing(subtract).` to see for yourself). The only difference is the list membership predicate, `var_memberchk/2`, which is defined like this:

```
var_memberchk(A0, [A1|_]) :- 
    A0 == A1, !.
var_memberchk(A0, [_|R]) :- 
    var_memberchk(A0, R).
```

This checks to see if a variable, atom or term is in the list. So, trying this we get:

```
?- subtract2([1,2,3,4],[3,4,_],L).
L = [1, 2].
```

Note that it still works if we name the variables, as you'd expect:

```
?- subtract2([1,2,A,3,B,4],[3,A,4],L).
L = [1, 2, B].
```

It also works if we explicitly give names to anonymous variables, like this:

```
?- subtract2([1,2,_A,3,_B,4],[3,_A,4],L).
L = [1, 2, _B].
```

Finally, note that since `_` doesn't have a name, `subtract2/3` will *never* be able to match it to other anonymous variables in either list, for example:

```
subtract2([1,2,_,4],[3,_,4],L).
L = [1, 2, _G415].
```

Where `_G415` is the anonymous global variable denoted by the `_` in the first input list. The second is a different global variable (like `_G416`, for instance), so could never match the anonymous variable in the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
% Uses list catenation to generate sublists /subtraction
conc([], L, L).

conc([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]) :-
    conc(L1, L2, L3).

% Finds all list members that have values and then
% use list catenation to generate the sublists
subtract(L1, L2, L3) :-
   findall(D, (nth0(N, L2, D), nonvar(D)), PureL2),
   conc(L3, PureL2, L1).
```

This assumes that only one list has  '_', but you could do the same findall for L1 if both lists have the same problem.